# how to pass a String to another String variable in another class?

Tags: java, android, string, class

i have this :

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String urlCorrecta="";


        //Si se escoge la posicion de el arreglo 0 abre la clase LasVegas
        if (position == 0)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            urlCorrecta = "souphttpsrc location=http://69.54.28.188:7878/mjpg/video.mjpg ! multipartdemux single-stream=true ! jpegdec ! autovideosink sync=false ";


        }

        //Si se escoge la posicion de el arreglo 1 abre la clase LosGuayabos
        else if (position == 1)

        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LosGuayabos.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            urlCorrecta = "souphttpsrc location=http://rax1.bsn.net/mjpg/video.mjpg?streamprofile=Balanced ! multipartdemux single-stream=true ! jpegdec ! autovideosink sync=false ";

        }

        //Si se escoge la posicion de el arreglo 2 abre la clase RegionalNorte
        else if (position == 2)

        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegionalNorte.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            urlCorrecta = "souphttpsrc location=http://trackfield.webcam.oregonstate.edu/mjpg/video.mjpg ! multipartdemux single-stream=true ! jpegdec ! autovideosink sync=false ";
        }


        //Si se escoge la posicion de el arreglo 3 abre la clase RegionalSur
        else if (position == 3)

        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegionalSur.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            urlCorrecta = "souphttpsrc location=http://wmccpinetop.axiscam.net/mjpg/video.mjpg ! multipartdemux single-stream=true ! jpegdec ! autovideosink sync=false ";

        }

    }
```

i want to pass the value of the String urlCorrecta to the String VIDEO_IN_PIPELINE located in the class MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{




    private final String VIDEO_IN_PIPELINE = VALUE OF THE STRING urlCorrecta;
    private final String HOST_IP = "192.168.1.167";
```

}

How can i take that String from the other class to this one?

thanks very much for reading.

Comment: Use `Intent.putExtra` for sending value to next Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the string from one activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ReceiverActivity.class);
intent.puExtra("key","String Value");
startActivity(intent);
```

To get String in `ReceiverActivity`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String str = intent.getExtra().getString("key");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use extras:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LosGuayabos.class);
intent.putExtra("myString", myString);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then you just need to get the intent in your onCreate method:

```
String myString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("myString");
```

Answer (score 1):

To pass it to another `Activity`, add it as an extra in your new `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("urlCorrecta", "souphttpsrc location=http://rax1.bsn.net/mjpg/video.mjpg?streamprofile=Balanced ! multipartdemux single-stream=true ! jpegdec ! autovideosink sync=false ");
startActivity(intent);
```

To retrieve it in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()`:

```
String urlCorrecta = getIntent().getStringExtra("urlCorrecta");
```

Try this. This will work.